# MySQL & PHP - How to convert date, time, and timezone when stored separately

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

In our application, we're currently storing date, time, and timezone separately. The date field is optional, which is why we have everything separated. For the user interface, they will specifically select a date, a time, and then a timezone. Everything is currently stored in UTC and the timezone would be an ID, which references another lookup table.

The way I understand and see it, we can display the date and time the user specified, simply by showing all three of those values without having to adjust anything. If they entered 11-30-15 6:00PM PST, that's what they'll see, formatted however we see fit.

- Are there any immediate issues anyone can think of doing it this way so far?
- How should I handle the time conversion? At some point in the system, it needs to understand the actual time. The system time is UTC, but if some work needs to be performed at 11:00AM PST, then it needs to know that. I'm wondering if there is an issue storing the time as UTC, but having them specify a timezone that is different. For example, the time is supposed to be PST, but is stored as UTC.

I am using Laravel with Carbon, just to provide more information. Any feedback would be great!

Comment: I think you better store a timestamp + user timezone than when retriving the date just convert it to the user local time using carbon

Answer (score 0):

Store whole date,time and timezone as a single column. Convert user entered time to GMT and store in db. When you need to display time to user convert GMT to USERTIMEZONE.

```php
function getGeneralTimeFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
}
```

```php
function convertDateTimeToGMT($dtime)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
    $dtzone = new DateTimeZone(getTimeZoneDateTime($_SESSION['USER_TIMEZONE']));
    $dtime->setTimeZone($dtzone);

    return $dtime->format(getGeneralTimeFormat());
}
```

```php
function convertGMTToLocalTime($timestamp)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
    $dtime = new DateTime($timestamp);
    $dtzone = new DateTimeZone(getTimeZoneDateTime($_SESSION['USER_TIMEZONE']));
    $dtime->setTimeZone($dtzone);

    return $dtime->format(getGeneralTimeFormat());
}
```